# How to setup Solr search across REST urls

Tags: search, solr

We are implementing an API Portal and have a field named basePath to hold the base part of the api's rest url.  Currently the field is defined as a string mapped to solr.StrField but we have search problems with this.

The problem right now is that in order to find an API by the basePath, we need double quote the value in the search.  For example `name:"/v1/api-proxy/generator"`  We cannot use `name:/v1/api-proxy/*`  to see other apis that might have clashing urls.  We know we have other urls like '/v1/api-proxy/validator' but something like `name:/v1/api-proxy/*` doesn't return any hits.

I am guessing a first step is to change away from 'string' to text or text_general, but how can search and find other hits that closely match the provided basePath?

Comment: `/` means a regex search. Escaping the value should work: `name:\/v1\/api-proxy\/*`. Going to a text field would mean that `api-proxy/v1` and `v1/api-proxy` both match, and you loose the possibility of searching by prefix (so you'd have both fields in that case). So whether that's correct will depend on you use case. For human search: maybe, sure; For programmatic search: hmmmmmno

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh, I think that will handle it.  It works for me in the Solr Admin screen, now I just need to 'reformat' the user input to escape that slashes when using the basePath.

Comment: The Solr library you're using should handle that for you - it probably has an escape function built-in

Comment: @MatsLindh -I am trying to debug our code now but I don't think it is escaping the query.  Could be a bit more specific about what I should be looking for?   Also, you should post as answer so I can accept your 'solution'. :-)

Comment: Since you haven't said anything about how you're searching or what you're using, so that's going to be hard - i.e. I have no idea whether you're using Java, Python, PHP, curl, or .. something else.

Comment: We are using Java.  Our UI has an input text field for the user to type in the search criteria.  They can entery some search terms or we have several fields indexed where then can add something like basePath:/v1/foo/bar.   This is passed to our solr backend thru REST.   The search value is passed as parm q with a value of the search terms.  Not sure if that helps or not.

Comment: SolrJ has a `ClientUtils` class that has `escapeQueryChars` that you can use to escape parts of your query string - however, if _the user_ is able to provide a field name as well, you'll want to split that into its own part first (and validate it!), so that you don't escape the `:` between the field name and the value you're searching for.

Comment: I have changed the code that calls Solr to hard-code something just to see if I was on the right track.   I added:

Comment: I am having problems translating from the Solr Admin to code.   Solr Admin works for me finding urls  with escaped search value.   But when I put the idea in code - it just doesn't find any hits?   I am logging the value after I escape the search value.  Here's what I see from my log:  AFTER: basePath:\\/v1\\/api\\-proxy\\/\\*  - intended to find urls like /v1/api-proxy/*.   I just get status 200 and no hits...

Comment: The issue is that you're escaping `*` as well. That shouldn't be escaped, since otherwise it will search for tokens containing `*` and not do a wildcard search.

Comment: That's being done by this code
`ClientUtils.escapeQueryChars(queryParts[1]);`  and I just kind-of noticed that and starting to debug it.   Looks like the ClientUtils is escaping it....

Comment: Yes, you'll have to drop escaping that part if you intend your users to be able to perform wildcard searches.

Comment: Success!   Thanks for all the help.  I am escaping the query and then 'un-escaping' on the * and works like a charm.